# How to calculate time complexity of the following algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, analytics, time-complexity

How to calculate time complexity of the following algorithm. I tried but I am getting confused because recursive calls.

```
power (real x, positive integer n)
//comment : This algorithm returns xn, taking x and n as input
{
    if n=1 then
    return x;
    y = power(x, |n/2|)
    if n id odd then
    return y*y*x //comment : returning the product of y2 and x
    else
    return y * y //comment : returning y2
}
```

can some one explain in simple steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out the time complexity of a recursive function you need to calculate the number of recursive calls that is going to be made in terms of some input variable `N`.

In this case, each call makes at most one recursive invocation. The number of invocations is on the order of O(log<sub>2</sub>N), because each invocation decreases `N` in half.

The rest of the body of the recursive function is O(1), because it does not depend on `N`. Therefore, your function has time complexity of O(log<sub>2</sub>N).

Comment: Is it alright to assume that if the recursion is reduced by n/2, then the complexity would have 'log n'

Comment: @user2684719 Not necessarily: you need to see what the body of the function is doing. For example, if there were a loop that repeated `K` times for each invocation, where `K` is the top-level `N`, then the complexity would be `O(N*Log2(N))`. If there were two invocations instead of one, the complexity would be `O(N)`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Each call is considered a constant time operation, and how many times will it recurse is equal to how many times can you do n/2 before n = 1, which is at most log<sub>2</sub>(`n`) times. Therefore the worst case running time is O(log<sub>2</sub>`n`).

Comment: Is it alright to assume that if the recursion is reduced by n/2, then the complexity would have 'log n'